# Можно ли изменить компонент Stylesheet на ходу в React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

Просто скажите это возможно изменить вот такой вот компонент

```
var styles = Stylesheet.create{
   block: {
      width: 50
   }
}
```

Таким вот образом

```
styles.block.width = 100
```

И применятся ли стили в этом случае

Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте. Если попробовать это сделать через переменную состояния, то возможно получится. Не видя ваш код, что вы делаете с styles дальше, сложно дать ответ

Comment: Почему нельзя сразу же использовать новое значение состояния сразу же после его изменения. Как это обойти

Comment: Реакт будет изменять данные только в том случае, если у компонента изменилось состояние.